# Linux support for new Sony Vaio Z external graphics card?

Tags: linux, usb, graphics

The new Sony Vaio Z series laptop comes with a media dock that has a USB connection (Light Peak) to an external AMD Radeon graphics card. What is the support for devices like this in Linux?

Comment: I'm curious: have you had any progress since asking this question? I have the same laptop, and everything works, except I can't get external monitors connected to the power media dock and I can't connect the dock to the computer if it's running.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis not much going on here, I am thinking the best chances are going to be in this mailing list: http://lists.launchpad.net/sony-vaio-z-series/

Comment: @avilella: Thanks to pointing me to the mailing list; it looks to be a useful resource. Do you have a Vaio Z as well?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: I used to have a Sony Vaio SZ and created the mailing list to bring Linux users together to share their expertise. Now I have an Asus U33JC.

Comment: @avilella: Since nobody's given a more useful answer than your comment--and your comment *is* useful--why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The best chances are going to be in this mailing list: http://lists.launchpad.net/sony-vaio-z-series